# Tornadofx Custom Table Cell

Tags: javafx, tornadofx

how to insert a button or any other kind of component in javafx tableview cell using tornadofx ?
I am in a situation where i have a column header "Action". I need to render several action buttons in the table view .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `cellFormat` function and assign a container with the buttons to the `graphic` property of the cell:

```
column("Name", SomeObject::someproperty).cellFormat {
    graphic = hbox(spacing = 5) {
        button("Action 1").action { doSomething() }
        button("Action 2").action { doSomethingElse() }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I will try it shortly. Thanks @edvin

Comment: Thanks, added double quotes :)